# Grabbing data from middleware form using jQuery in Django

Tags: jquery, django

I have a middleware like this:

```
class PostModelFormMiddleware(object):

def process_request(self, request):

    form = PostModelForm()
    request.post_form = form
```

This form has a captcha field. What I want to happen in my template is everytime a person hits Submit the captch question refreshes by Javascript to a new one. How do I grab that `request.post_form` and its data in jQuery?

Thank you!

EDIT: More code.

The HTML:

```
   <form id="add_post">
...
        <input type="hidden" name="math_captcha_question" value="fbc9fcdffbf2b2723ab36e9f341372214daf1be936202d2035">
    6 - 5 = 
...
    </form>
```

I would like to change the value of "math_captch_question" as well as the displayed text. Both of these are initially displayed using the template tag `{{request.post_form.math_captcha_question}}`

The jQuery:

```
 $("form#add_post").submit(function() {
 //Validations and stuff
            var data = {category:category, body:body, nickname:nickname, math_captcha_question:math_captcha_question, math_captcha_field:math_captcha_field};
            var args = {type:"POST", url:"add_post/", data:data, complete:function(res, status) {
                //Process response
                //This is where I would like to set new values for math_captcha_question

            } };

            $.ajax(args);
        }


        return false;

    })
```

/add_post/ view:

```
def add_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
           #do stuff
           return HttpResponse("success")

        else:
            return HttpResponseServerError("fail")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to output the form in your template first, give it an `id` or other identifier and then you can access it via jQuery.

```
<form id="myform" ...>
    {{request.post_form}}
</form>
```

Edit: I am assuming you have `'django.core.context_processors.request'` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

**Update** (according to comments below):

Your `add_post` view need to return something in the response `jQuery.ajax` can deal with. If it is just returning `"success"` there will be only plain text in the response. To make it easy you should return the new `math_captcha_question` value:

```
def add_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       #fill some data in the form
       form = PostModelForm(request.POST)
       if request.post_form.is_valid()
            math_captcha_question = form.cleaned_data["math_captcha_question"]
            return HttpResponse(math_captcha_question)
       else:
            return HttpResponse("error")
```

In the callback in jquery you can then deal with the values you get and give a user friendly response accordingly. In you on `complete` callback:

```
function(res, status) {
    if (res!="error") {
        $("form#add_post #id_math_captcha_question").attr("value", res);
    } else {
        //show some error to your user
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yeah I already have it in the template. What I don't know how to do is to grab the new form that the middleware spits out through jQuery. I know how to replace old value with new value through jQuery. This new value is floating... somewhere... I tried to figure it out through Firebug, but I couldn't find it. Ideas?

Comment: Hm, can't really help without some code snippet from your side (the jQuery part you want to replace the value for a field in the form).

Comment: My guess is that you get the new value for `math_captcha_question` from the response of the POST request? Before you use jQuery I would suggest you to add an `id` or `class` to the `math_captcha_question` input. Assuming the `id` is `"id_math_captcha_question"` you should then be able to do something like `$("form#add_post #id_math_captcha_question").attr("value", new_value_from_post_response);` in the lines you mentioned in you JS.

Comment: Ok, then one last code addition I think: How does your view handling the post request to the url "add_post/" look like? Btw. "add_post/" looks like a relative URL. Maybe its better to use absolute URL's kike "/add_post/", simply to avoid URL dependency issues.

Comment: Actually the new value of `math_captcha_question` is computed in `PostModelFormMiddleware.process_request()`, my first piece of code, which is executed everytime a request comes in. The POST response itself is just text that says `success` or `fail`. I hope that makes sense...

Comment: See my edits in the answer. Though I think the way you are doing it is confusing (using middleware and view). Just the view should be enough. The middleware is definitely the wrong approach when validating a form.

Comment: Wait, you also use the middleware to diplay the form in the first place (I forget). In this case you can keep the middleware. Even better would be a context processor though. Just make sure you use the `PostModelForm` directly for validation in your view like in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes actually the only purpose the middleware serves is to serve a form on every template. I didn't want to have to return a form in every view that I have. This way seemed more straightforward. Yeah, I figured I have to return the values I wanted in the view's response. I actually want the captcha to be updated regardless of success or error. I might return a simple JSON response to help. Can you tell me more about how to replace the middleware with context processor? Thanks!

Comment: About context processors check http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors. Its way easier then dealing with middleware's. Each view which is rendered with `context_instance = RequestContext(request)` will then use the context_processors provided in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting`. If you are not attempting to change request or response objects and you just need a variable in all views which render templates then choose context processors over middleware.